# Spring bean post processor that supports @Value and is destruction-aware?

Tags: spring

I want to write Spring BeanPostProcessor which needs some configuration injected e.g. by @Value properties and performs some extra cleanup on another bean destruction.

[DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.html) has postProcessBeforeDestruction() method which is triggered before destruction and it could do the job. However, it does not support @Value-annotated properties. As explained in [@Value javadoc:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) *Note that actual processing of the @Value annotation is performed by a BeanPostProcessor which in turn means that you cannot use @Value within BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types. Please consult the javadoc for the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class (which, by default, checks for the presence of this annotation).*

So I turned to [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) which however does not have method to intercept bean destruction (as it does not inherit from DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor)

Is there some BeanPostProcessor type that combines both features? Or is there an easy way to write one?

Comment: Would the `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations to the job for you?

Comment: @Ralf probably not because I want to execute my cleanup code against third-party class bean and `@PreDestroy` is annotation to use inside bean component class itself